# Creating a home directory for a user

Tags: linux, settings

Hi I added a user using useradd command so that he have no home directory:

```
useradd -M -u 1110 brinst
```

Then I wanted too add a home directory for the same user using usermod but that didn't work out:

```
 usermod -m -d /home/lagha brinst
 usermod: no changes
```

How can I create a home directory with all it's folders and hidden files for this user when he doesn't have an old one? - that seems to be easy but somehow it's not working.

Comment: The subdirectories (Documents, Downloads, etc...) are automatically created when the user first logs in through GNOME, provided that the home directory is created with the correct permissions                                                                                                               'sudo mkdir /home/testinguser,                                                               'sudo chown testinguser:testinguser /home/testinguser reference http://askubuntu.com/questions/335961/create-default-home-directory-for-existing-user-in-terminal

Comment: Actually this command will just create a home dir for the user but without all hidden files:                                                                                        .bash_history
.bash_logout
.bash_profile
 .bashrc
 .viminfo

Comment: what linux version are you using. That thread I posted has all the different ways to do it. Including a version using the 'useradd -m' version.

Comment: I'm wotking on CentOs 7.3

Answer (score 7):

```
mkdir /home/brinst
usermod -d /home/brinst brinst
```

More cleaner way:

```
mkhomedir_helper brinst
```

Answer (score 0):

create user with command like

```
sudo useradd my-new-user -m -d /home/my-new-user
```